# "mountall main process executable changed" causing long boot times

Tags: 11.04, boot

I am desperately trying to improve my machine's boot time but I cannot succeed. For now I have spotted that in the verbose boot mode it stops for a longer time on this line :

```
mountall main process (316) executable changed
```

[image: bootchart graph]

This is the content of fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=03c40d10-2200-4e00-8430-a020e8fd1f23 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=e3729117-b936-4c1d-9883-aee73dab6729 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Edit:

I've tried the following:
1. I've reinstalled ureadahead using these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ureadahead
```

2. I've removed any files with a file name of "pack" in /var/lib/ureadahead and rebooted.  Another pack file was created successfully.

I forgot to mention : I have this script running on boot (according to some tutorial): `/etc/init.d/bootopts #!/bin/sh (/sbin/ureadahead --daemon)&`

EDIT2:

I added results of my hard drive test  :
[image]

although nothing is wrong when I boot Windows :/

Comment: I have added the content of fstab to the question description but can you please elaborate a little more on: `Also can you confirm that removing the pack files from /var/lib/ureadahead together with aptitude reinstall ureadahead has been done.` And I forgot to mention : I have this SCipt running on boot (according to some tutorial): `/etc/init.d/bootopts

#!/bin/sh
(/sbin/ureadahead --daemon)&`

Comment: I do not know why are you advising that but my system cannot fund a command `sudo aptitude`

Comment: Ok, even though I did reinstall and I rebooted ureadahead did not create any *.pack files in the /var/lib/ureadahead folder (there is only a "pack" file and a folder "debugfs"

Comment: @fossfreedom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1201/discussion-between-lordmonkey-and-fossfreedom)

Comment: I'd definitely remove that bootopts script. Do you see anything in the `dmesg` output that would suggest a failing hard drive? You can also run a S.M.A.R.T. test (Alt+F2 → palimpsest → select your drive on the left and then run the test: Smart Data → Run Self-test).

Comment: @htorque "Do you see anything in the dmesg output that would suggest a failing hard drive? " what do you mean by this ? (how to check it) ? I have added results of my hard drive's test

Comment: Can you also add the lower part of that screen (something like "Reallocation Count" would be interesting)?

Comment: Have you tried to remove that startup script? And in where tutorial do you find the advice to use it?

Comment: @enzotib Not yet. I did not really tried and didn't have time. I will post an update when I do this.

Answer (score 1):

The data you added is sufficient to say: your hard drive will probably fail soon. One reallocated (bad) sector is not bad per se, but given your bootchart issue I'd say: immediately back up your data (start with the more important stuff) and keep an eye on that sector count. If it raises in the near future, replace the hard drive.

Comment: 1) Can I fix the bad sector ?
2) That may be related to my disc problems lately (I have reallocated a partition and failed and then I had some major issues with partition table). Am I right that this might be related ?

Comment: OK, so one year has passed and my hard drive is still fine (with this one bad sector) :)

Comment: That's great! :)